# ajax post call not working

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to call MVC Controller from jquery but not able to place the call. Is there any problem in below code
Please figure out that if any problem and also I am not getting any error.

url="http://localhost:49917/Account/SaveAddress"

```js
this.SaveAddress = function (url, addressData)
    {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(addressData),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (responseDetail) {
                   },
                error:function(e)
                {

                },
            });
    return 0;
};
```

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveAddress(AddressListViewModel addressListVM)
    {
        bool response;
        string message;
        if (addressListVM.ID <= 0)
        {
            response = await Task.Run(() => AccountManager.Instance().AddAddress(addressListVM));
            message = response ? "New address added successfully." : "Failed to add new address.";
        }
        else
        {
            response = await Task.Run(() => AccountManager.Instance().UpdateAddress(addressListVM));
            message = response ? "Selected address updated successfully." : "Failed to update selected address.";
        }
        ModelState.Clear();
        return Json(new { responsestatus = response, message = message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //return PartialView("_AddressDetail", BuildAddressListEntity(
        //                                UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()), response, message, addressListVM.ID, true));
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying it's not hitting the controller method at all? As a side note, `ModelState.Clear();` is pointless (you returning json, not a view/model) and you not actually doing anything with the data you return.

Comment: And your `url` value should not be hardcoded like that - it should be `url="/Account/SaveAddress"` (and preferably generated with `@Url.Action()`)

Comment: In Google Chrome, load your page and then hit F12 to open developer console. From there, click Network. After that call your ajax method from the page and see if any request fired or not in developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing a closing bracket at the end of the this.saveaddress function

```
  this.SaveAddress = function (url, addressData)
  {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(addressData),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (responseDetail) {
               },
            error:function(e)
            {

            },
        });
```

after all of that .. you need one more closing bracket:

```
   }
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

What does the console display? If you are using Chrome then right-click, choose Inspect, and find the Console tab. If you are calling the AJAX function correctly then something must be displayed in this Console tab which will probably lead you in the right direction better than I could with the information I have.

Comment: that's why I'm confusing

Comment: How are you calling the function this.SaveAddress? The code you provided simply defines the function but never puts it to use.

Comment: var promisePost = RestService.SaveAddress('http://localhost:49917/Account/SaveAddress', AddressInfo);

Comment: Looks like there is a semi-colon after the first parameter which is not correct syntax.

Comment: it is display only in comment but there is actually  not semicolon on code

Comment: Have you used the debugger; statement? It's a really handy tool to debug and step through JavaScript code. It's much like placing a debug breakpoint in Visual Studio except you are using the browser to step through code. You must have the developer console open to catch the debugger; statement and start debugging. Check out this documentation for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint in your success and error functions. If it hits the error function then the issue is either that the controller action was not found or that the data is not valid json (either the post data or return data). You should add the errorThrown parameter to the error function so you can easily see what the issue is. You also do not need to stringify the data if it is already valid json, but if it is a string representing json data, you will need to use json.parse (sorry for the incorrect case).